Determine whether the series is convergent or divergent.
I've been working to determine if $$\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\ln x}}$$ is convergent or divergent.
$$\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\ln x}} = \frac{1}{2^{\ln 2}} + \frac{1}{3^{\ln3}} + \frac{1}{4^{\ln4}} +\cdots = \frac{1}{1.6168}+\frac{1}{3.3433} +\frac{1}{6.8333} + \frac{1}{13.3336} +\cdots $$
And this would be less than $$ \frac{1}{1.6}+\frac{1}{3.2} +\frac{1}{6.4} +\frac{1}{12.8} +\cdots = \sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{0.4 \cdot 2^{x}} = \frac{1}{0.4}\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{x}} $$
Since $$\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{x}}$$ converges, then does that mean that the original series also converges by the comparison test? Is this a correct approach?

Try an integral test: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BIntegrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bx%2Cln%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D%2Cn-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D

While the overall approach is correct, the supposed inequality $1/x^{\log x} < 1/0.4\cdot 2^x$ for all $x$ is not correct.

Yes, if you prove that $\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln n}} < \dfrac{1}{0.4 \cdot 2^n} \ \forall n$, then your proof would be complete.
Alternatively, as we have $\ln n > 2$ for $n \ge 8$, we obtain $\dfrac{1}{n^{\ln n}} < \dfrac{1}{n^2} \ \forall n\ge8$. As a result,
$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\ln x}} \ &= \ \underbrace{ \sum_{x=2}^{7} \frac{1}{x^{\ln x}} }_{ = C < \infty } \ + \ \sum_{x=8}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\ln x}} \\
&\le \qquad C \quad \ + \ \sum_{x=8}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \\
&< \qquad C \quad \ + \ \underbrace{ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} }_{=\pi^2/6} \\
&= \qquad C \quad \ + \ \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{align}$
Hence, the sum is bounded by above by a positive constant; therefore, $\boxed{ \text{it converges} }$.
